# Margin of Button inside LinearLayout not working

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-button

In my project, I'd like to have two `Button`elements in a `LinearLayout` without space between them.

I've tried to set `padding` and `margin` to `0dp`, to remove `style` and to remove `ScrollView` but nothing works.
I can't figure out a way to remove the space between buttons.
Do you have some ideas?

My XML is:

```
     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- The first child in the layout is for the main Activity UI-->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


</LinearLayout>

<!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:background="#ffeeeeee"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="0dp" >

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/agenda"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/agenda_icon"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/day"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/agenda_icon"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/month"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/agenda_icon"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But the result is (I've touch the last two buttons to show the button background):
[image: result image]

Setting `padding` of each Button to 0 (@aga answer) doesn't solve my problem :(
[image]

Comment: it might be due to your style just try removing it for a check

Comment: @KaranMer I've already tried. Same result.

Comment: @ArchitJain your suggestion doesn't work :(

Comment: @matteolel : just in case check that you haven't provided margin or padding or divider values in navigation drawer

Comment: @KaranMer thanks. I've edit my question, including all my XML. I've already tried to remove `ScrollView` and add margin or padding of inner `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the color of the button, because the default interface of the button which is native to android is center-fitted to make it look cool.

Change the background color of the button to match the color of the layout in which it is placed, then we will get the real size of the button.
In your case

```
android:background="#000"
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this since it does not use the style it may get rid of some issues by setting the width to a hard coded size and by uses default paddings

```
<Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_overtime"
                    android:layout_width="310sp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:text="Overtime"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: While this code may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation would help current and future readers to understand your answer even better.